# Angular build - Unexpected token ] in JSON

Tags: angular, tsconfig

After spending what feels like several hours going through numerous npm installs just to find an angular & material compatible solution, I think I might be close to finally being able to run my app...

However, upon using 'ng serve' I receive the following error. This Tsconfig file hasn't changed for awhile, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

> error TS5014: Failed to parse file 'mylocation/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 329.

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "allowJs": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "types": [
   "node",
   "hammerjs",
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
   "../node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
   "es2017",
   "dom"
  ]
},
 "files": [
  "typings/index.d.ts"
 ]
}
```

Any assistance in trying to figure this one out would be awesome. I think I've gone a bit snow blind.

Comment: remove , after `"hammerjs"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a extra comma on `"hammerjs",`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "hammerjs"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That actually worked. I feel like crying a bit...thanks Igor! (I can accept an answer in 8 minutes)

Comment: @ETX - likewise. Thanks!